How do we treat those from Ahlul Kitab whom lived before the Prophethood of Muhammad SAW by a few decades?
I’m just curious as to what status do these people get within Islam? As by this point of time some would have died on what was Islam at that point, it might be a bit silly to ask such a question, yet is it permissible to pray for them? As in calling for rahmat allah (allah yarhamah) upon them?

This answer should help:
https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/108914
So depends on the Dua, if it is asking for them to go Jannah, or be guided. And all of that is explained there.
Let me know if this answers the question
